# How to type a React component that accepts another component as a prop, and all of that component's props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, emotion

I've got a React component `<Wrapper>` that I can use as follows:

```
// Assuming Link is a component that takes a `to` prop: <Link to="/somewhere">label</Link>
<Wrapped as={Link} to="/somewhere">label</Wrapped>
```

If no `as` prop is passed, it will assume an `<a>`. But if a component is passed to `as`, all props that are valid for that component should now also be valid props of `Wrapped`.

Is there a way to type this in TypeScript? I was currently thinking along these lines:

```
type Props<El extends JSX.Element = React.ReactHTMLElement<HTMLAnchorElement>> = { as: El } & React.ComponentProps<El>;
const Wrapped: React.FC<Props> = (props) => /* ... */;
```

However, I'm not sure whether `JSX.Element` and/or `React.ComponentProps` are the relevant types here, and this does not compile because `El` can not be passed to `ComponentProps`. What would the correct types there be, and is something like this even possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The tyes you need are `ComponentType` and `ElementType`.

```
import React, { ComponentType, ElementType, ReactNode } from 'react';

type WrappedProps <P = {}> = { 
  as?: ComponentType<P> | ElementType
} & P

function Wrapped<P = {}>({ as: Component = 'a', ...props }: WrappedProps<P>) {
  return (
    <Component {...props} />
  );
}
```

With that, you are able to do:

```
interface LinkProps {
  to: string,
  children: ReactNode,
}
function Link({ to, children }: LinkProps) {
  return (
    <a href={to}>{children}</a>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Wrapped<LinkProps> as={Link} to="/foo">Something</Wrapped>
      <Wrapped as="div" style={{ margin: 10 }} />
      <Wrapped />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Super! This is exactly what I was looking for. And even relatively straightforward, great.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could go something like this:

```
import React from 'React';

type WrappedProps = {
  as: React.ReactNode,
  to: string;
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet

Comment: Unfortunately that's not want I'm looking for - `to` shouldn't be a hardcoded prop of `Wrapped`. Instead, if it's a prop of whatever component is passed to `as`, TypeScript should infer that it's also a prop of `Wrapped`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
type Props = {
  as?: React.FC<{ to: string, children: any }>,
  to: string,
  children: any
}

const Wrapped: React.FC<Props> = ({ as: El, to, children }) => (
  El
    ? <El to={to}>{children}</El>
    : <a href={to}>{children}</a>
)
```

Then you can use with an `as` prop:

```
<Wrapped as={Link} to="/somewhere">label</Wrapped>
```

...or without to default to the `<a>` element:

```
<Wrapped to="/somewhere">label</Wrapped>
```

---

Further to your comment below, if you want `Wrapped` to accept the props of the component passed to the `as` prop then I'm not sure how to do this or if it's possible.

However, you could try something like this:

```
<Wrapped as={<Link to="somewhere">{label}</Link>} />
```

...so passing `Link` to the `as` prop in this way means that you don't need to pass the props to `Wrapped`.

```
type Props = {
  as?: React.ReactNode
  children: any
}

const Wrapped: React.FC<Props> = ({ as, children }) => (
  <>{ as ? as : <a href="/somewhere">{children}</a>}</>
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not want I'm looking for - `to` shouldn't be a hardcoded prop of `Wrapped`. Instead, if it's a prop of whatever component is passed to `as`, TypeScript should infer that it's also a prop of `Wrapped`. So in your examples, `Wrapped` without an element passed to `as` shouldn't accept the `to` prop.

Comment: So you want `Wrapped` to accept the props of the component passed to the `as` prop?

Comment: Exactly. (Specifically, I want TypeScript to understand that it accepts them.)

Comment: I have updated my answer with another possible solution. Hopefully it's of some use.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a generic component that is already styled for both mobile and web view; and would like to wrap other components in it, rather than repeating the same html tags, you can make it a generic component, like so;

```
const ComponentForAllViews = (props: React.PropsWithChildren) => {
    return(
        <div className="class-name-for-generic-view">
        </div>
    )
};
```

Then, other components can be written as;

```
const Login = () => {
    return(
        <ComponentForAllViews>
            ...Your login htmls
        </ComponentForAllViews>
   )
};
```

```
const Register = () => {
    return(
        <ComponentForAllViews>
            ...Your register htmls
        </ComponentForAllViews>
   )
}
```