# How to type an object that contains a React component as a property and also that component's props as another property?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Let's say I got an object that structured as follows:

```
{
  Component, //<--- the component
  props, //<--- the props of the component
}
```

I would like to create a generic type for this object so that it accepts a `component` and infer that component's props type as the `props` property.

This is the type I try to create by referring to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61148557/how-to-type-a-react-component-that-accepts-another-component-as-a-prop-and-all) and it doesn't as I expected.

```
type Object<P = {}> = {
  Component: React.ComponentType<P> | React.ElementType;
  props?: React.ComponentProps<typeof P>;
} & P;
```

My implementation

```
doSomething({
  Component: AnotherComponent,
  props: {
    ...// AnotherComponent's props
  }
})
```

`doSomething` is a function that accepts the `object` as a parameter.

I am very new to typescript and I couldn't find my answer on TS documentation. I will be very grateful if someone could guide me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a generic interface where the props are the generic parameter, and then you construct the component type from those props.

```
interface WrapComponent<P> {
    Component: React.ComponentType<P>
    props: P
}
```

Now in your function just be sure to forward the generic parameter to the interface so the right prop types can be inferred:

```
function doSomething<P>({ Component, props }: WrapComponent<P>) {
    return <Component {...props} />
}

doSomething({
    Component: ({ a }: { a: number }) => <>{a}</>,
    props: { a: 123 },
})
```

[See typescript playground for working example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOpTgBwMIHsC2muIE4APAAoB8yA3gFDJPJ6HGlgBcyAShImAB0rIiXAAVAJ6YIlKo2aYouTAGduFegF969GAFcQCMMGLIAJrgDKBCGAAWoAOZyAFLRYFRHADTIlKqrIWtzoWCLs5NQAlHQKTFB2+lAgyGQRYmB0gjkBalrIAPTyOvSWNvh2jiBO7vGebJnc7shwwdwecNwg+vgARtDBsQC8NGRUtHBaZMU+9XnqdK3cAIwATADMwXNa0bqFhcjijkHAQW1g0ijQylCtQRAAHjLGEOZ+qqBIyA4oCxaYZAgXBZfBYH64H72FAILyRIRlay2BzOOrMBrecDNTrtJZdIG9AZ3XbIUZpCZTGZUObohYdZAARwA7tBLqtNtttNEgA)

Comment: Brilliant! This works perfectly. This example helps me to understand generic typing better. Thank you so much!