# Typescript generic and React components

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm attempting to write a universal wrapper component that accepts an `as` prop which indicates the element to render and also requires any props that the element being rendered requires. With help from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61148557/how-to-type-a-react-component-that-accepts-another-component-as-a-prop-and-all), I have a working example:

```
import React, { ComponentType, ElementType, ComponentProps } from "react"

type WrapperProps<P = {}> = {
    as: ComponentType<P> | ElementType
} & P

const Wrapper = <P = {}>({ as: Element, ...rest }: WrapperProps<P>) => <Element {...rest} />

const Link = ({ href }: { href: string }) => <a href={href}>Click Me</a>

const Test = () => <Wrapper as={Link} /> // Should error as `href` is missing.
const Test2 = () => <Wrapper as={Link} to='/' /> // Should error as `to` is not a valid prop.
const Test3 = () => <Wrapper as={Link} href='/' /> // Should compile.
```

I'm unable to wrap my head around why the `Wrapper` component requires it's own generic type `P`. In other words, why this wouldn't work:

```
const Wrapper = ({ as: Element, ...rest }: WrapperProps) => <Element {...rest} />
```

The type `WrapperProps` already defines `P` as a generic which defaults to an object. Why must I redefine that when typing `Wrapper`? Is React/TS somehow passing a value for this variable automatically when I call `Wrapper` and if not, what extra information does that compiler get from me duplicating the declaration that `P` defaults to an empty object?

**Update**

I wanted to provide some additional context. I understand that if I were to define this type inline, I would need to add the generic to `Wrapper` as obviously it needs to come from somewhere:

```
const Wrapper = <P = {}>({ as: Element, ...rest }: {
    as: ComponentType<P> | ElementType
} & P) => <Element {...rest} />
```

I also understand that I were passing an explicit type for the generic when calling `Wrapper` then `Wrapper` would need it's own generic to be able to "pass" that to `WrapperProps`:

```
<Wrapper<ComponentProps<typeof Link>> as={Link} href='/' />
```

What I'm missing is that since I am **not** passing any type to `Wrapper` why do I need it to accept a generic? In other words, the type `WrapperProps` already knows that the type `P` defaults to an empty object, why does the function `Wrapper` need to redeclare this?

It seems redundant for `Wrapper` to set `P` to an empty object and then pass that type to `WrapperProps` as `WrapperProps` could have just set it's own `P` to an empty object.

Comment: You don't have to set a default generic for `Wrapper`, but then it would be a required generic, which might be frustrating to use.

Answer (score 1):

`Wrapper` is a function that must take an argument. The argument is of type `WrapperProps`, which is generic.

If you didn't make `Wrapper` generic, then `WrapperProps` would either need to declare its generic type explicitly or else it would fall back to its default:

```
// WrapperProps is implicitly WrapperProps<{}>
const Wrapper = ({ as: Element, ...rest }: WrapperProps) => <Element {...rest} />

const Wrapper = ({ as: Element, ...rest }: WrapperProps<Link>) => <Element {...rest} />
```

In this sense, it's no different than a chain of two function, where you want to pass a value to the first so that it can pass it to the second:

```
function foo(p = {}) { return p; }
function bar(p = {}) { return foo(p); }

bar({ baz: "value" }); // returns { baz: "value" }
```

Comment: Thanks! Isn't the value I'm passing `P = {}` already the same as the implicit value of `P` in `WrapperProps`? Your function analogy makes sense but only when `bar` is called with a non-empty object. E.g. `bar()` is identical to `bar({})`.

Comment: @user1032752 - Wrapper is being assigned a generic anonymous function. For example, given `const foo = <T>(a:T) => T`, then `foo` is a function that will return the same type as the argument it's passed. E.g. `foo(123) // returns number`, `foo("apple") // returns string`

Comment: I appreciate your help and while I understand your examples, I'm failing to understand how it applies to my question. I've added some more context to my question if you don't mind taking a look.